# Hide and show another table in the same section with back button

Tags: jquery, html, css, angularjs

I have a section containing a table.
I want to hide the table whenever an element in that table is being clicked and show another table in the same  without reloading the page. 
I want also to show a back button so I can return to the initial section.
Thanks

```
<section class="tabs" id="content3">
      <table class="rwd-table">
<tr>
  <th>Livre</th>
  <th>Article de journal</th>
  <th>Chapitre de livre</th>
  <th>Conférence avec actes</th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td data-th="Livre"> <a href ="#">2008</a></td>
  <td data-th="Article de journal">CESACO 2012-2015</td>
  <td data-th="Chapitre de livre">M-Trace 2010-2013</td>
  <td data-th="Conférence avec actes">M-Trace 2010-2013</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td data-th="Livre">RSE 2010-2013</td>
  <td data-th="Article de journal">CESACO 2012-2015</td>
  <td data-th="Chapitre de livre">M-Trace 2010-2013</td>
  <td data-th="Conférence avec actes">M-Trace 2010-2013</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: It would help a lot if you add what you already have.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I've added my html code in the post.

Comment: on clicking this table which table should be shown?

Comment: Another table that has not been created yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you aren't clear in your question we can't give clear answers. Just use hide() to hide the clicked table. Use show() to show the table/button that have to be shown.

```
$('#table1').on('click', function(){
$(this).hide();
$('#table2').show();
$('#backbutton').show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Given is a sample code which fulfill your requirements.This is done with angularjs.

Please update as per your need.

view

```
<button ng-click="back()">Back</button>

<table id="tableId" border="1" ng-show="table1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Table 1
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <button ng-click="selectElement()">Element</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<table id="tableId" border="1" ng-show="table2">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Table 2
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                column
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

js controller

```
function MainController($scope) {
  $scope.table1 = true;
  $scope.table2 = false;

  $scope.selectElement = function(){
         $scope.table1 = false;
     $scope.table2 = true;
    };

   $scope.back = function(){
         $scope.table1 = true;
     $scope.table2 = false;
    };
}
```